# Springboot cannot find my autowired bean despite all scanning

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

So I have a class called `ClientFactory` that I import into my project using a jar. It looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ClientFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    public ClientFactory() {
    }

    public Client get() {
        return this.client;
    }
}
```

and my class that uses this looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"path.to.client.*"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ProjectClient {

    @Autowired
    public ClientFactory clientFactory;

    public ProjectClient() {}

    public String getSomething(String something){

        Client client = (Client) clientFactory.get();
        return "x";

    }
}
```

And I call this piece of code from my test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Disabled
@TestPropertySource(properties = { //
        "some.property=value", //
})
public class SomeTests {

     @Autowired
     ProjectClient p;

     @Test
     public void sampleTest() throws Exception {
            p.getSomething("sample");

     }
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
Field clientFactory in ProjectClient required a bean of type 'ClientFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ClientFactory' in your configuration.
```

I've tried all combinations of Entity, Component and Package scans but nothing seems to be working. The application simply cannot find that bean, I've googled high and low and can't seem to find a way to get this working - I'm new to Spring boot - please help :(

Comment: can you show your pom.xml file

Comment: 1.[`@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation) is already meta annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. 2. The `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class should ideally be the start of your program , hence a `main()` method is expected there. 3. `@ComponentScan` relies on the package structure. Could you please share the exact package structure for the classes involved  and a minimal working example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please include the package declarations in your code snippets. Also your code doesn't make sense. Your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation should be on an application start class, in other words a class with a `main` method. Not on some arbitraty class like this. `@SpringBootApplication` already implies `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: @M.Deinum My main class has that annotation, and yet if I don't include that annotation on top of that class, it fails with that error :( I removed `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and just left the `@ComponentScan` in place (with the `@SpringBootApplication` and it works :/

Comment: Your `ProjectClient` should be an `@Component` (or the likes) and you should prefer the `scanBasePackages` over `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this class isn't compiling properly.

```
@Component
public class ClientFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    public Factory() {

    }

    public Client get() {
        return this.client;
    }
}
```

While Class name is **ClientFactory** the constructor been defined as **Factory**, which isn't possible for compiler to compile it.

Would you please change **Factory to ClientFactory** *(OR Remove default constructor If you don't have specific use)* and try again

Comment: I'm sorry, I sort of didn't want to expose the real code - I shall edit this

Answer (score 0):

Create `clientfactory` with bean annotation since you are referring `clientFactory` by importing from jar

```
@Bean
    public Clientfactory clientfactory () {
        return new Clientfactory ();
    }
```

Comment: I cannot modify `ClientFactory`

Comment: add this in your main class of spring boot application dont modify the client factory

Answer (score 0):

It took me too long but I figured it out. I made a change to `ProjectClient` as follows:

```
@Service
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"path.to.*"})
public class ProjectClient {
```

I'm guessing my path to client was incorrect or undetectable (I used the same path for importing that class).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have forgotten to add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` on your test class.

Comment: As I understand, you set not only one package as a base package here `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"path.to.client.*"})`.

I have tried to make a project with the same structure and context started correctly in the test. I guess there is not enough info in the question. Since you can't share your project structure and etc I can recommend you create a small test project with the same structure and try to run a test on it. Maybe it will be helpful

Comment: He is using JUnit5 which doesn't need that as that is for JUnit4.

Comment: @MaximPopov I had to make a slight change to my packages that were being scanned, and it worked!